# Eigenvectors of a matrix with trigonometric entries

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The standard method (Characteristic polynomial) for the eigenvectors of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin(y)\cos(z) & \sin(y)\cos(x) & \sin(x)\cos(z) \\
\sin(y)\cos(x) & -\sin(z)\cos(x) & \sin(z)\cos(y) \\
\sin(x)\cos(z) & \sin(z)\cos(y) & -\sin(x)\cos(y) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
leads to a complicated polynomial (degree 3) that cannot be easily solved.
Is there any other methods for the eigenvectors of this particular matrix (there are a lot of symmetry inside)?